# Finding the UMVUE of $\theta^2$ where $f_X(x\mid\theta) =\frac{x}{\theta^2}e^{-x/\theta}I_{(0,\infty)}(x)$

Tags: self-study, estimation, inference, exponential-family, umvue

> Let $X_1, X_2, . . . , X_n$ be iid random variables having pdf
>
> $$f_X(x\mid\theta) =\frac{x}{\theta^2}e^{-x/\theta}I_{(0,\infty)}(x)$$
>
> where $\theta >0$. Give the UMVUE of ${\theta^2}$

I was recently asked this on an exam and I wanted to see if my solution was correct.

I first noted that $f(x\mid\theta)\sim\text{Gamma}(2,\theta)$ depending on how you choose to parameterize it. We have an exponential family and can let
$w(\theta)=-\frac{1}{\theta}$ and $t(x)=x$. Since

$${\{w(\theta):\theta\gt0\}}={\{-\frac{1}{\theta}:\theta\gt0\}}=(-\infty,0)$$

contains an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, $T\left(\vec{X}\right)=\sum t(X_i)=\sum X_i$ is a complete statistic and it's also a sufficient statistic. Since $E(X)=2\theta$ then perhaps something similar to $\left(\frac{\bar{X}}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\left(\sum X_i\right)^2}{4n^2}\right)$ will be unbiased for $\theta^2$. We know that $T\sim\text{Gamma}(2n,\theta)$ so

$$\begin{align*}
\mathsf E\left(\frac{\left(\sum X_i\right)^2}{4n^2}\right)
&=\frac{1}{4n^2}\int_0^{\infty} t^2 \frac{1}{\Gamma(2n)\theta^{2n}} t^{2n-1}e^{-t/\theta}dt\\\\
&=\frac{\theta^2\cdot(2n)\cdot(2n+1)}{4n^2}\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}\frac{1}{\Gamma(2n+2)\theta^{2n+2}}t^{2n+1}e^{-t/\theta}dt}_{=1}
\end{align*}$$

Hence $$\frac{\left(\sum X_i\right)^2}{4n^2}\cdot\frac{4n^2}{2n(2n+1)}=\frac{\left(\sum X_i\right)^2}{2n(2n+1)}$$ is unbiased for $\theta^2$ which is a function of the complete sufficient statistic $T$ and so by the L-S theorem it's the unique UMVUE of $\theta^2$.

Is this a valid solution? I would also be interested in alternative approaches if you have one.

Comment: You can check this from the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) itself since $E(T)=2n\theta\,,\operatorname{Var}(T)=2n\theta^2$ implies $E(T^2)=\operatorname{Var}(T)+(E(T))^2=2n\theta^2(1+2n)$.

Comment: I feel so stupid. It would have been a lot easier this way!